# Integration of Laplacian on Manifold (Hopf's Lemma ?)

Tags: integration, hodge-theory, laplacian

Well,

Let $M$ a compact manifold and $dM = \star 1$ the volume element, $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$.
Define the inner product of $p-forms$ like:
$(\omega,\theta) = \int_M \langle \omega, \theta \rangle dM = \int_M \omega\wedge \star \theta$
Is true that :

$$\int_M \Delta f \star 1 = 0$$

because $(\Delta f,1) = (f,\Delta 1) = 0$.

But, if we put $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ been  $f(x) = x^3$ . So, $\Delta(f) = 6x$.
Then, $\int_{[0,1]} f(x)dx = 3(1)^2 = 3$.
So, what is wrong ?
Is this theorem false ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplacian is self adjoint only if you apply it to functions with suitable boundary conditions.
Try to show that the Laplacian is self adjoint on a Euclidean domain or an interval and you will see boundary terms appear.
This is what happens in your example.

If you work with a closed manifold, there is no boundary and hence no issue.

Comment: Joonas Ilmavirta, sorry, I did not understand the problem. I have prove that the laplacian is self-adjunt using that (dω,θ)=(ω,δθ). For ω∈Ωp−1(M) and θ∈Ωp(M). I didn't have to impose boundary conditions.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi, if your manifold has boundary and you impose no boundary conditions on the forms, your codifferential operator is not the adjoint of the differential. Does $(d\omega,\theta)=(\omega,\delta\theta)$ hold for $M=[0,1]$ without any boundary considerations?

Comment: Thank you ! Now I understand.

Comment: How i vote on your answer ???

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi, click on the arrows next to the number (now zero) next to answer to vote up or down. You can also accept one of the answers by clicking by clicking the roughly V- or J-shaped figure below the down arrow. I suggest you take the tour that you can find under the help button in the upper right corner.